# different versions on pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pepper

I am working on my graduation project and I need to use 2.7 python version because of the naoqi library, at the same time I want to work on 3.7 versions because of other library. I have to take the output from 3.7 and show it on the pepper robot which is 2.7 library so how can I work with these two at the same time?

Comment: You can configure a virtual environment (venv) with pycharm and work with different python versions with different projects. See: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html

Comment: What Nir said about venv will work - but you'll need to install both python 2.7 and 3.7 on your machine which can easily get messy. My suggestion would be to use conda (miniconda) which handles different python versions very cleanly and integrates with pycharm just as well as venv.

Comment: You need to split your main project into two projects one for each Python version used since AFAIK Pycharm doesn't support multiple python versions within the same project

Comment: Please answer the question, not comment it.